# Angular Authentication Not Successful with angular-auth-oidc-client@11

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update the authentication strategy for my Angular app, using the [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client) package. I was on an older version, but wanted to update to the latest version of the package. I went through all the migration steps, and everything compiles just fine, but I'm seeing an issue after the app goes to the auth server and comes back.

As a background, our Angular app is on v9, and we're authenticating on a self hosted Identity Server 4 instance. We were using Implicit Flow, but are trying to move to code flow with PKCE.

When the app loads, we load the needed configuration for the auth server from a file (so that it can be different in each environment) and then there's a "login" button that the user clicks to go to the auth server. We go to the auth server and then back to the Angular app. The component that we come back to is /auth/callback, where the `checkAuth` method is called on the `OidcSecurityService` from `angular-auth-oidc-client`. That's where the issue comes in though. The app can't finish authenticating. Some errors occur and the authentication doesn't finish. I set the `LogLevel` to `Debug` and got this output in the console:

[image: Error from attempted authentication]

There's nothing here really to help me understand what is going on or why the authentication fails, other than perhaps that the `/connect/token` endpoint returned a 400. But if I provided all the configuration that the library requires, there's not a whole lot that I can do about that, correct?

If anyone has any tips or can help in any way that'd be great. I'm also going through the logs on our authentication server to see if I can figure anything out there.

Comment: Can you check the response you're getting from 400 error in web devtools Network tab?

Comment: The response is "invalid_client", but the client definitely exists. The logs say that the secret validation failed. But we're not sending the secret (and weren't before with the implicit flow) and I'm assuming that's because it's a single page app and not a backend app.

Comment: This means that you need to check which  `client` you're sending to that request.

Comment: So we were using the right client, but were missing a few attributes. You can see the attributes below in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't say this is an answer for everyone, but this did work for us. We needed to add the following attributes to the client definition:

```
RequirePkce = true,
RequireClientSecret = false,
AllowOfflineAccess = true
```

Adding these three attributes to the client definition made everything work as expected.